# GNS3 Connection to real network

Tags: networking, emulation

I have this topology in GNS3 Project on Windows 7:[image: two muppets]

PC (C5) is managed by vpcs as described in this tutorial: http://www.gns3.net/gns3-hosts-topologies/.

R1-R3 - emulations of Cisco 7200 routers.

Cloud is connected to router by NIO MS loopback adapter (my real PC) as described in this tutorial: http://www.gns3.net/gns3-connecting-real-networks/.

Device IP configuration:

C1:

```
ip - 9.9.9.9

Mask - 255.255.255.0

Default Gateway - 9.9.9.7
```

R1 e1/1:

```
ip - 9.9.9.7

Mask - 255.255.255.0
```

R1 e1/0:

```
ip - 9.9.8.1

Mask - 255.255.255.0
```

R2 e1/1:

```
ip - 9.9.7.1

Mask - 255.255.255.0
```

R2 e1/0:

```
ip - 9.9.8.2

Mask - 255.255.255.0
```

R3 e1/1:

```
ip - 9.9.6.1

Mask - 255.255.255.0
```

R3 e1/0:

```
ip - 9.9.7.2

Mask - 255.255.255.0
```

C5:

```
ip - 9.9.6.2

Mask - 255.255.255.0

Default Gateway - 9.9.6.1
```

The problem is:

I can ping from PC(C5) or any router to any devices in the network (except C1).

I can ping Cloud (C1) from R1.

I can ping only R1 from Cloud (C1).

Example:

C1 > ping 9.9.9.7   // - it works.

R1 > ping 9.9.9.9   // - it works.

C5 > ping 9.9.9.7   // - it works.

C5 > ping 9.9.9.9   // - it does not work.

What can it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add routes to your PC for the 9.9.6.0, 9.9.7.0, 9.9.8.0 to gateway 9.9.9.7. Try typing these commands in the command prompt on the PC:

```
 route ADD 9.9.6.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 9.9.9.7
 route ADD 9.9.7.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 9.9.9.7
 route ADD 9.9.8.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 9.9.9.7
```